# John M. Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds: push forward in local coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, pushforward

On page 50 of John M Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds about the local coordinates of the pushfoward $F_*$ it says

$$\left( \left. F_*\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right|_{p} \right)f = \frac{\partial(f\circ F)}{\partial x^i}(p) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y^j}(F(p))\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(p) = \left( \left.\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\right|_{F(p)}\right)f.$$

I don't fully understand the very last equation. Could someone elaborate how the last equation comes up?

Prior to posting this question i searched for an answer but couldn't find any, i hope this is not a duplicate.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you gotta understand is that $$\left( \left.\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\right|_{F(p)}\right)$$ is a tangent vector at $T_{F(p)}N$, and as such it "eats" germs of functions at $F(p)$ and spits out a real number. Tangent vectors are linear operators, so if $v = v^{j} \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y^{j}}\right|_{F(p)}$, then $v(f) = v^{j} \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{j}}\right|_{F(p)}$. In your case, the $v^j$ are given by $\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(p)$, therefore:

$$\left( \left.\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\right|_{F(p)}\right)f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y^j}(F(p))\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(p)$$

Keep in mind we're using Einstein notation here.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, i didn't notice the einstein notation (still need to get used to it i'm afraid). Does your last equation (the centered one) satisfy commutativity? I wasn't sure if that's the case here.

Comment: Or asked differently, could we also have written

$$\left( \left.\frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial y^j}\right|_{F(p)}\right)f = \frac{\partial F^j}{\partial x^i}(p)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^j}(F(p))$$

Comment: Yes, since it's just multiplication of two real numbers. Don't let all the notation and indices obscure that basic observation.

Comment: beautiful, thank you vm @Deane. I have indeed some difficulties with all the indices but slowly getting used to it. Really appreciate your help.